# PostgreSQL settings on Mac

Tags: postgresql

After attempt of all bases and uses deleting, I try to set postgresql again.
For this purpose I try to change the superuser password.
I enter in console

```
  MacBook-Pro-Andrej:~ andrej$ sudo su - postgres
```

And system requests password.
But what the password may be, when I changed pb_hba.cfg as follows

```
local          all            all                              trust

 # IPv4 local connections:
 host          all            all      127.0.0.1/32     trust

 # IPv6 local connections:
 host         all            all      ::1/128               trust

 local    replication      all                                trust
  host     replication     all       127.0.0.1/32         trust
  host      replication    all        ::1/128               trust
```

in Log

```
 FATAL: database "andrej" does not exist
```

But what is database "andrej", when I deleted all bases?
I try to delete this base ones more:

```
 sudo -u postgres dropdb andrej
```

But system requests password...

Comment: PostgreSQL configuration doesn’t affect your operating system’s configuration. It’s asking for the OS user’s password, not a PostgreSQL user.

Comment: ahhh, yes... I mixed this definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You start your command with **sudo** so you are prompted for your OS password. Try to provide that password and the command should execute without any problem.

Comment: The problem have been solved, after I uninstalled postgresql.app